# lodash / angular 8 : find valid index in array and test with if statement

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement, indexing, lodash

I'm working on e-commerce angular application and in the basket I have 2 types of products : a couple of restaurant + spectacle and giftCard, when client reserve a restaurant should reserve a spectacle with it and Conversely, client can add multiple couples of restaurants and spectacles, and he can add multiple giftCards to the basket. the command button will be disabled if :

1- a couple of restaurant/ spectacle missing item ( spectacle or spectacle )

this the html of basket :

```
<div id="mySidenavv" class="sidenavv">
  <div class="mySidenavv-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 Mon-panier ">Mon panier </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeSideNav()"><img
            src="/assets/img/double-right-arrows-angles.png" alt="">
        </a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row Divider"></div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="cartItem" *ngFor='let item of cartItems; let i = index; '>
        <div *ngIf="!item.type">
          <div (click)="goToDetails( i )" class="row"
            *ngIf='item.spectacle && item.placesListContent.length > 0 ; else defaultSpectacle'>

            <div class="col-4 image-content">
              <div class="card-img" [style.background]="'url(' + item.spectacle.sp_visuel + ')'"></div>
              <div class="= Bg-Circle ">
                <div class="col-md-2 Combined-Shape ">
                  <button type="button" class="close " aria-label="Close"
                    (click)="removeFromCart(item.spectacle.sp_id, i, 'spectacle')">
                    <img src="/assets/img/times-circle-solid.svg" class="img-close" alt="">

                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="row item-title">
                {{item.spectacle.sp_nom}}
              </div>
              <div class="row line" *ngFor='let place of item.placesListContent'>
                <img src="/assets/img/tickets.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details">{{place.tr_qte}} {{place.tr_intitule}}</div>

              </div>
              <div class="row line">
                <img src="/assets/img/calendar.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details date">{{ item.placesListContent[0].tr_seance* 1000   | date : 'le d MMMM  y'}}</div>

              </div>
              <div class="row line">
                <img src="/assets/img/clock.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details">{{ item.placesListContent[0].tr_seance* 1000  | date : 'HH:mm'}}</div>

              </div>

              <div class="row line-div">
                <div class="col-8 small-Divider"></div>
                <div class="col-4 price">{{item.spectacle.total | number : '1.2-2' }} €</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #defaultSpectacle>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 image-content">
                <div class="card-img" [style.background-color]="'#dddfe7'"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="row item-title">
                  <a (click)="goToShows(i,'restaurant')">Trouver un spectacle</a>
                </div>
                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/tickets.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="Details">A déterminer</div>

                </div>
                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/calendar.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="Details date">A déterminer</div>

                </div>
                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/clock.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="Details">A déterminer</div>

                </div>

                <div class="row line-div">
                  <div class="col-8 small-Divider"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 price">-</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <div (click)="(item.restaurant && item.spectacle) ? goToDetails( i ): ''"
            *ngIf='item.restaurant ;else defaultRestaurant;' class="row">
            <div class="col-4 image-content">
              <div class="card-img" [style.background]="'url(' +serverUrl+'/'+item.restaurant.image+ ')'"></div>
              <div class="= Bg-Circle ">
                <div class="col-md-2 Combined-Shape ">
                  <button type="button" class="close " aria-label="Close"
                    (click)="removeFromCart(item.restaurant.id, i, 'restaurant')">
                    <img src="/assets/img/times-circle-solid.svg" class="img-close" alt="">

                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="item-title">
                {{item.restaurant.name}}
              </div>
              <div class="row line">
                <img src="/assets/img/calendar.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details date" *ngIf='item.restaurant.time'>
                  {{ item.restaurant.time* 1000   | date : 'le d MMMM  y'}}</div>
                <div class="Details date" *ngIf='!item.restaurant.time'>A déterminer</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row line">
                <img src="/assets/img/clock.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details" *ngIf='item.restaurant.time'>{{ item.restaurant.time* 1000  | date : 'HH:mm'}}
                </div>
                <div class="Details" *ngIf='!item.restaurant.time'>A déterminer</div>

              </div>

              <div class="row line">
                <img src="/assets/img/tray.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                <div class="Details">
                  <span class="comma"
                    *ngFor="let formule of item.restaurant.selectedPlacesRestaurant ">{{ formule.libele }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="row line-div">
                      <div class="col-8 small-Divider"></div>
                      <div class="col-4 price">{{item.restaurant.price}} €</div>
                    </div> -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #defaultRestaurant>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 image-content">
                <div class="card-img" [style.background-color]="'#dddfe7'"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="item-title">
                  <a (click)="goToRestaurants(i,'restaurant')">Trouver un restaurant</a>
                </div>
                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/calendar.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="to-be-determined">A déterminer</div>

                </div>
                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/clock.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="to-be-determined">A déterminer</div>

                </div>

                <div class="row line">
                  <img src="/assets/img/tray.svg" class="tickets-img" alt="">
                  <div class="Details">Formule : Entracte</div>

                </div>
                <div class="row line-div">
                  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 price"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <div class="row Divider"></div>

        </div>


        <div class="item-container" *ngIf="item.type && item.amount">

          <div class="cartItem">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 image-content d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
                <div class="mask">
                  <img class="type-icon" [src]="serverUrl+'/'+item?.icon" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="= Bg-Circle d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
                  <div class="col-md-2 Combined-Shape-card d-flex ">
                    <button type="button" class="close " aria-label="Close" (click)="removeFromCart(item,i,'type')">
                      <img src="/assets/img/times-circle-solid.svg" class="img-close" alt="">

                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-6 align-self-center gift-card-desc pl-0">
                <p class="type-desc">{{item.qte}} Chèque cadeaux Spectacle + Restaurant <span
                    class="gift-type">{{item.type}}</span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 align-self-center gift-card-desc pl-0">
                <p class="type-price">{{item.totalPrice}} € </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div (click)="goToDetails()" class="row">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="cart-footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 purchases-continue"><a (click)="closeSideNav()" class="a">Continuer mes achats</a></div>
        <div class="col-6 totale"> Total : {{ total || 0 | number : '1.2-2' }} €</div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-submit form-control  btn-block" (click)='goToCommand()' [disabled]="disableBookBtn">
        <p class="command">Commander</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

and here the ts file :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.serverUrl = environment.serverUrl
    this.cartService.myCart$.subscribe(res => {
      this.total = 0
      this.giftCardsTotal = 0
      this.cartItems = this.cartService.getItemCard() || res
      if (this.cartItems.length == 0) this.disableBookBtn = true
      this.cartItems.forEach(item => {
        debugger
        let indexEmptyItem = _.findIndex(this.cartItems, item => { return (!item.restaurant || !item.spectacle || !item.placesListContent || item.placesListContent < 1)})
        let giftItemIndex  = _.findIndex(this.cartItems, item => { return (!item.type)})
        debugger
        if (indexEmptyItem == -1 || giftItemIndex == -1)
          this.disableBookBtn = false
        else
          this.disableBookBtn = true

        // let itemPrice = 0
        // if ( item.placesListContent ){
        //   item.placesListContent.forEach( value => {
        //     itemPrice += ( value.tr_reduit || value.tr_tarif)*value.tr_qte
        //   });
        //
        //   let price_restaurant = 0;
        //   if(item.restaurant && item.restaurant.price) price_restaurant = item.restaurant.price*1
        //   itemPrice +=  price_restaurant
        //
        // }else{
        //   itemPrice = 0
        // }
        // if()

        if (item.spectacle) this.total += item.qte * item.spectacle.total
        if (item.type) this.giftCardsTotal += item.totalPrice
      });
      this.total += this.giftCardsTotal

    })

    setTimeout(() => this.cartService.initCart(), 100)
```

}

the if statement and findIndex function not return a valid result !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is an overkill and you're using the findIndex in the wrong way, you can simply achieve the desired result by modifying the code to-

```
    this.cartItems.forEach(item => {
        const indexEmptyItem = !item.restaurant || !item.spectacle || !item.placesListContent || item.placesListContent < 1;
        const giftItemIndex = !item.type;
        this.disableBookBtn = (indexEmptyItem || giftItemIndex) ? true : false;
        // do other operations based on each item
      })
```